# How to update a post using react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to create a blog website where I want that the user can save their post and edit the same post later. I'm confused as to how to make the website know that I want to edit this specific post using snippetId and also want the website to know if it's a new post or if I opened an existing post to edit so that when I open a post to edit then the title and textarea is filled with the values received from the redux store.

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dijkstra-7u3o4) for it.

Editor.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { savePost, retrievePost } from "./actions/posts";

class Editor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "", //should I assign them using snippetData.snippetTitle since if it's a new post then it'll be null anyway
      enteredText: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //Load the snippet
    retrievePost(); // will it load the snippetId too?
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
  };

  // Save Snippet
  performSave = snippetData => {
    const { enteredText, title } = this.state;
    savePost(snippetData.snippetId, enteredText, title); //is it the right way to send the parameters to save the post??
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="titletext"
          placeholder="Enter title here"
          limit-to="64"
          className="inptxt"
          onChange={title => this.setState({ title })}
        />
        <button
          className="btn savebtn"
          onClick={() => this.performSave({ ...this.state })}
        >
          Save Snippet
          <i className="fas fa-save" />
        </button>

        <textarea
          name="enteredText"
          onChange={enteredText => this.setState({ enteredText })}
        >
          {}
        </textarea>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  snippetData: state.snippetData
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { savePost, retrievePost }
)(Editor);
```

actions.js file

```
import { SAVE_POST, UPDATE_POST, RETRIEVE_POST, HOME_LOADED } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
export const savePost = ({
  snippetId,
  snippetDescription,
  snippetTitle
}) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  let snippetData = { snippetId, snippetDescription, snippetTitle };
  try {
    if (snippetId == null) {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "/api/save",
        JSON.stringify(snippetData),
        config
      );
      snippetData.snippetId = res.data;
      dispatch({
        type: SAVE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    } else {
      await axios.post("/api/update", JSON.stringify(snippetData), config);
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

// Retrieve post

export const retrievePost = snippetId => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/snippetdata/${snippetId}`);
    dispatch({
      type: RETRIEVE_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

//Retrieve all the post
export const onLoad = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/mysnippets/`);
    dispatch({
      type: HOME_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

// edit a post
```

reducer.js

```
import {
  SAVE_POST,
  UPDATE_POST,
  RETRIEVE_POST,
  HOME_LOADED
} from "../actions/types";

import { initialState } from "../store";

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SAVE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetData: payload
      };
    case UPDATE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetData: payload
      };
    case RETRIEVE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetData: payload
      };
    case HOME_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippets: payload
      };
    case "SET_EDIT":
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetToEdit: action.snippet
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you dont have to `this.performSave({ ...this.state })}`. You already are in the class, so you can simply:

```
 performSave = () => {
    const { enteredText, title } = this.state;
    savePost(snippetData.snippetId, enteredText, title);}
```

//is it the right way to send the parameters to save the post??
  };

You are getting "Cannot read property 'snippetId' of undefined" because you never defined snippetData properly.

You can access parameters by `this.props.match.params.snippetId`. See [react-router-url-parameters](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/).

So the final save method should be:

```
  performSave = () => {
    const { enteredText, title } = this.state;
    savePost(this.props.match.params.snippetId, enteredText, title);}
```

Comment: and how do I load the input and textarea fields with the data already from the server if a post exist already, i.e if I open a post to edit then I want those fields to be filled already with the data

Comment: also, suppose if I save the post then immediately I won't have the id in the url, so I think it's better to fetch the id from the store than match.params.url to save again without leaving the editor else I think there will be duplicate copies of the same post with different ids

Comment: Without seeing any code, if i need to load something on an edit component receiving the id in that way, i will execute a fetch (or action, whatever) on useEffect or ComponentWillMount, depends if you are using classes or hooks. You can add a loading action for async fetch.
If you are saving and you need that id, you can modify your backend API to return the id on success save.

Comment: this is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dijkstra-7u3o4 can you look and help me where to call the id that match it is that specific that needs to be edited and load the input and textarea with it's existing values? like wordpress, you see all your post, then click on any of them to edit and the texteditor loads with the saved text

Comment: the api returns id, snippetTitle and snippetDescription from the backend.. something like ```{
  "snippetDescription": "Honestly some of it is probably dynamic difficulty", 
  "snippetTitle": "demo", 
  "snippetid": "caf3358d-050f-4507-b2ef-54060967cda0"
}``` so it's sending the id from the api too which can be used using mapStatesToProps. I will do the fetching part using redux thunk. but I'm not sure how to load the editor with already existing data. can you please help me?